# Pip not getting installed

Tags: python, pip

**C:\Python>python get-pip.py
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002EDF31D2AD0>, 'Connection to 10.1.1.9 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/**

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlZuH.png)

I'm trying to install pip on my windows 11. I have navigated to the directory in which Python is installed. And yet, I am constantly getting the same error again and again. I haven't configured anything yet. Please guide me through the complete procedure right from the beginning by installing python.

Comment: what python distribution did you install, and no pip built in?

Comment: What is `10.1.1.9`? Proxy? Private network? Something feels off there.

Comment: I know nothing. Please drop a message on my email "nimishmaheshwari1998@gmail.com" so that we can go through my problem in depth. I have been trying to resolve this issue for a while now.